# Handling html and jsp files

Tags: html, jsp, web

I have created a front end of web page(html file) but now  I want to retrive some data from server and dispaly that data on webpage.And I realised that it will require JSP.But as my front html file is too big to enter java code which will make it difficult to maintain.Is there any way that I can keep .html and .jsp file totally seprate.
Please give a small demo for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can include different .jsp files in each other.
See:
[JSP include Directive](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/include_directive.htm)